# Variável não definida em query de SQL para PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, mysqli, xampp

Estou tentando enviar para um array em PHP, uma query com as informações de uma tabela em MySQL, mas estou encontrando o seguinte erro quando tento imprimir uma posição do array:

> **"Notice: Undefined variable: array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Domiritmo\Inicio.php on line 104"**

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
<?php                  
  $sql = "SELECT msgNAutor, msgTAutor, msgTipo, msgTopicos, msgTexto, msgData FROM tbmensagem";
  if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $array = array();
    if (!$result) {
      die("Error: ".mysql_error());
    }               
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $array[] = $row;
    }   
  }                                           
?>
```

A posição do array que tentei executar e que ocorreu o erro acima foi:

```
<?php
  print_r($array[0]['msgNAutor']);
?>
```

Desculpe-me se já perguntaram sobre esse erro aqui na comunidade, mas procurei em vários sites e não encontrei a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema!
Utilizei as funções **mysqli** ao invés da **mysql**, além de algumas alterações.
Segue abaixo o novo código:

```
<?php                                 
          $sql = "SELECT msgNAutor, msgTAutor, msgTipo, msgTopicos, msgTexto, msgData FROM tbmensagem";             
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $array = array();              
            $index = 0;                                                     
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array[$index] = $row;
                $index++;
            }
          mysqli_free_result($result);
          mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```